# What's the name of this interface in Mac SDK?

Tags: macos, input, interface, sdk, alert

Trying to make an interface that takes a few inputs from a user over a few screens.  Like the setup for Dropbox (below).  Can anybody tell me how to do this, or what the interface unit is called?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's typically known as a "wizard" or "assistant" interface.

There is no standard component in Cocoa for implementing these interfaces, but there are a number of libraries available which implement it, including [TESetupAssistant](https://github.com/taoeffect/TESetupAssistant).